# How to update only a part of all entity attributes with Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, orm

I receive a JSON with 30 fields, and my entity is built from this JSON.
The problem is: two fields shouldn't be updated (two dates).

If I use `entity.merge`, both fields will be updated.

How can I avoid that those 2 fields get updated?

Maybe using criterion.Example?

Is there some way to do this without me writing a ton of HQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you never want to update those two fields, you can mark them with [`@Column(updatable=false)`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-update-only-a-subset-of-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/):

```
@Column(name="CREATED_ON", updatable=false)
private Date createdOn;
```

Once you load an entity and you modify it, as long as the current `Session` or `EntityManager` is open, Hibernate can track changes through the dirty checking mechanism. Then, during `flush`, an `SQL` update will be executed.

If you don't like that all columns are included in the `UPDATE` statement, you can use a dynamic update:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Product {
   //code omitted for brevity
}
```

Then, only the modified columns will be included in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Could you also elaboate on `@SelectBeforeUpdate` (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SelectBeforeUpdate.html) ? Because `@DynamicUpdate` indeeed updates only the changed coulns but when my entity contains 5 foreign keys before and updates it selects all this relationships even though they are not changed. I would like to get rid of this unnecessary selectes before and update. For me @SelectBeforeUpdate(false) does not work the way i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this example :

```
    public class UpdateMethodDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Student s = studentService.getById(1);
            s.setNom("FuSsA");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(s);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }

}
```

**Edit:**

you can use `@Transient` annotation  to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database.

Comment: Thank you. I know this is an option, but maybe there is something simpler.